# Cannot Find Symbol in ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, compiler-errors, jgrasp

I'm writing a java class and I keep hitting an error.

> Paragraph.java:21: error: cannot find symbol 
>  ArrayList array; 
>  ^ 
>  symbol:   class ArrayList 
>  location: class Paragraph
>
> Paragraph.java:32: error: cannot find symbol 
>  array = new ArrayList(); 
>  ...................^ 
>  symbol:   class ArrayList 
>  location: class Paragraph

I imported the java class arrays at the very top of my program and it looks like this.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

The exact part of code I'm having errors with is...

```
private ArrayList<String> array;
public Paragraph()
   {
       array = new ArrayList<String>();
   }
```

This is part of an assignment were I have to use ArrayList.

Comment: it does not have these symbols <>, you used these ()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should import `java.util.ArrayList`, not `java.util.Arrays`. `Arrays` doesn't seem to be used in your program and these are two completely different classes.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having parentheses you should use <>

```
private ArrayList(String) array;
```

change to

```
private ArrayList<String> array;
```

your import is wrong for ArrayList

```
java.util.Arrays
```

change to

```
java.util.ArrayList
```

Comment: It is like that in my program but I could not get it to show up right on here

Comment: it says this --> private ArrayList<String> array;
in my program but on this site when I was typing in my question it would not show the String part so I put it in parentheses to show I actually has the String part in my program

Comment: JessNicole27 already said "it actually has these symbols <> around the String sections".

Comment: @user1509183 here I see parentheses not <> private ArrayList(String) array;

Answer (score 1):

your `array` declaration should be like this:

```
 private ArrayList<String> array;
 public Paragraph()
 {
           array = new ArrayList<String>();
  }
```

import

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
```

Comment: this format still caused the same errors and the public Paragraph() is my constructor

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the Arrays class you imported is not the ArrayList class. You need to have `import java.util.ArrayList;` at the top instead.